# Make Highcharts column chart bars as wide as mandated by a linear xaxis

Tags: highcharts

I have this Highcharts column chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/ltherond/bmk71a8r/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Column chart with negative values'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'linear'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPadding: 0,
                pointPlacement: 'between',
                shadow: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [{
                x: 0,
                y: 5,
                color: "#00FF00"
            }, {
                x: 500,
                y: -3,
                color: "#FF0000"
            }, {
                x: 600,
                y: 5,
                color: "#00FF00"
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

I want the first bar to extend horizontally from 0 to 500 on the xaxis.

In other words, I want each bar to start at the current x value and end at the next x value.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can vote for such feature in Highcharts on the [UserVoice](http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-highcharts-javascript-api/suggestions/2303560-multi-dimensional-column-charts).

Comment: You could do something similar using an area chart, and the step property:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bmk71a8r/4/

Comment: @PawełFus That is indeed what I need.

Comment: @jlbriggs This produces the same effect, but it requires augmenting the data with extra points. In this case, every 100 units on the x axis. How do I programmatically figure out how many points I need to add in the general case? It's probably workable, but it's a bit of a hack.

Comment: @laurent - no it doesn't. I used the wrong fiddle a base, apparently. Look at this one: http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bmk71a8r/5/   It does require one extra point at the end to make it look as you described. But it works now, as opposed to hoping that eventually enough people vote for a feature request and it gets implemented :)

Comment: @jbriggs I thought you had it until I realized you end up creating multiple series to achieve the appearance of what I am looking for. In my case, each column represents a range. All ranges are contiguous and sequential. Furthermore, the x axis will be in unit of distance and a second series will be indexed using that same distance axis.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `connectNulls` for your series attribute

From my knowledge this options is only available for Area and Line Charts and no longer available for column or bar chart

I recommend you to change your Chart Type to area chart and use `connectNulls` option as mentioned in Documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series%3Cline%3E.connectNulls)

To meet your requirement in Column chart itself you need to tune your data you fed into High chart as follows in your series code segment

```
series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [{
            x: 0,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        },{
            x: 100,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        },{
            x: 200,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        },{
            x: 300,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        },{
            x: 400,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        }, {
            x: 500,
            y: -3,
            color: "#FF0000"
        }, {
            x: 600,
            y: 5,
            color: "#00FF00"
        }]
    }]
```

This will solve your problem. see the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bmk71a8r/3/

For this approach you need to write extra codes to format your Data

Good Day

Comment: Thanks, you insert extra points in the original data, so connectNulls has little effect here. Otherwise, your solution is identical to jbbrigs'.